# k8s - pod can ping external ip, but cannot wget?

Tags: kubernetes, microk8s, calico

Running a clean install of microk8s 1.19 on Fedora 32, I am able to ping an external IP address, but when I try to wget, I get "no route to host" (this is the output of commands run from a busybox pod):

```
/ # wget x.x.x.x
Connecting to x.x.x.x (x.x.x.x:80)
wget: can't connect to remote host (x.x.x.x): No route to host
/ # ping x.x.x.x
PING x.x.x.x (x.x.x.x): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from x.x.x.x: seq=0 ttl=127 time=1.209 ms
64 bytes from x.x.x.x: seq=1 ttl=127 time=0.765 ms
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found https://github.com/ubuntu/microk8s/issues/408

Had to enable masquerade in the firewall zone associated with the bridge interface, or in my case, my ethernet connection.